# Ruby on Rails 4: Form Send me to index, cant find the reason

Tags: forms, redirect, submit, commit

i made a form with basic stuff, but instead of validating things and commit them to the Database, it calles my index method (what in fact gives me a routes error, because i dont allow POST towards the index view). Can someone give me a hint, why the form did that?

Here is the Form itself:

```
<%= form_tag(@weapon) do %>
  <div class="WeaponGenerate">
    <table>
      <th><h1>Eine neue Waffe erschaffen</h1></th>
      <tr>
        <td>Welche Sorte Waffe soll es sein?</td>
        <td><%= select_tag :art, options_for_select(['Schwert', 'Axt', 'Bogen']) %></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Der Name für die Waffe soll sein?</td>
        <td><%= text_field_tag :name %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Angriffswert</td>
        <td><%= number_field(:angriff,  in: 1..6, step: 1) %></td>
    </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Blockwert</td>
        <td><%= number_field(:block,  in: 1..6, step: 1) %></td>
      </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Zustand?</td>
      <td><%= number_field(:zustand,  in: 1..100, step: 1) %></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td><%= button_tag('Waffe erschaffen') %></td>
    </table>
  </div>

<% end %>
```

Here is the Controller (weapons_controller.rb)

```
class WeaponsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @weaponlist = Weapons.sorted
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @weapon = Weapons.new({:name => "DEFAULTNAME!"})
  end

  def create
    @weapon = Weapons.new(weapon_params)
    if @weapon.save
      flash[:notice] = "Schwert erschaffen!"
      redirect_to(:action => 'show')
    else
      flash[:error] = "Leider gab es ein Problem!"
      redirect_to(:action => 'new')
    end
  end

  private
  def weapon_params
    params.require(:weapon).permit(:art, :name, :angriff, :block, :zustand)
  end

end
```

my routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resource :weapons
  resource :user

  root 'pages#index'
  post 'user/new' => 'user#new'
  post 'weapons/new' => 'weapons#new'
  get 'pages/cobalt'
  get 'pages/hilfe'
  get 'pages/contact'
  get 'pages/impressum'
  end
```

Suggestions, anyone?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Formtag helpers are magicless. The `form_tag` helper method requires an explicit url for the action endpoint.

```
form_tag ("/weapons")
#or more rails way
form_tag (weapons_path)
```

[FormTag Helpers](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag)

But you have a pretty standard form. I'd use the more intelligent form_for helper, which works with objects.

Just run

```
 rails g scaffold Gweapon name:string angriffwert:integer blockwert:integer
```

and check the code it produces for the update and create forms

Comment: Thanks for that man! Commonly i use Form_for but .. i have no clue how thats happen ^^

Now i have to investigate why:

      def weapon_params
        params.require(:weapon).permit(:art, :name, :angriff, :block, :zustand)
      end

ends up in:

param is missing or the value is empty: weapons